# Cokernel of morphism of reflexive sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. Suppose $F$ and $F'$ are reflexive sheaves such that $F\subset F'$ and they both have the same determinants.

Suppose rank $F<$ rank $F'$. Then consider the cokernel, it is of trivial determinant. Then is $F'/F$ also reflexive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cokernel may not be even torsion-free, so it may not be reflexive. Also, if it is not torsion-free, determinant is not a very good notion. Even when it is torsion-free, it may not be reflexive. For the last part, consider the inclusion $O(-2)\to O(-1)\oplus O(-1)$ over the projective plane given by $(x,y)$, two homogeneous co-ordinates. Then the cokernel is the ideal sheaf $I=(x,y)$, which is not reflexive.

Comment: But the rank $F'/F>0$, even then it may not be torsion-free?

Comment: Sure. For example, take $F=O(1)\oplus O(-1)$ and $F'=O$ over the projective line with any non-zero map $F'\to F$ (which exists and thus injective), but the cokernel will always have torsion.